# ExchangeService Class to read Gmail, Hotmail email account

Tags: c#, imap, exchange-server

Can I read my emails from Gmail/Hotmail account using ExchangeService class.

Comment: I don't believe so. It looks like `ExchangeService` is pretty tightly bound to EWS.

Answer (score 0):

ExchangeService can only be used to access Exchange Web Services, it does not support IMAP protocol.

You may try using [Mail.dll IMAP component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) it supports IMAP and most Gmail extensions.

Please note that this is commercial product I created

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to this area and I need to create an application to read email from company email or public email ids (like gmail/hotmail). Now how I will come to know which email (gmail/hotmail/Company email) is based on which protocol. Is there any way I can get this information programmatically?  Thanks in advance.